# Cannot change state interface in react+typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the bellow code, im getting a compilation error, I can't change in closeLeftCol the state:
`Cannot assign to leftWidth because it is a constant or read only property`:

```
    interface ILayoutState{
        rightClassName: string,
        leftClassName: string,
        leftWidth: string,
        rightWidth : string
    }

    export default class Layout extends React.Component<undefined, ILayoutState> {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                rightClassName: "right-col slide-in", leftClassName: "left-col slide-in", leftWidth: '' ,rightWidth : '' };

        }

        closeLeftCol() {
            this.state.leftWidth = "0";
            this.state.rightWidth = "100%";
            this.state.leftClassName += " hideme";
            this.state.rightClassName += " full";
            this.forceUpdate();
        }

        render() {...}

}
```

Why am i able to change it in the contructore? what makes it read only?
[image]

Comment: @AndrewLi isn't that implicit? why do i need to decalre the type? its already decaler when in inheriting..

Answer (score 1):

**[Never mutate this.state directly](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state)**, always use [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update the `state` values.

Write it like this:

```
closeLeftCol() {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
          leftWidth : "0",
          rightWidth : "100%",
          leftClassName : prevState.leftClassName + " hideme",
          rightClassName : prevState.rightClassName + " full"
     }));             
}
```

Comment: Can we use `=` in setState?  Shouldn't it be a valid js object?

Comment: oh sorry my mistake (copy paste error), we can't use `=` because it's an object we need to use `:`. check the updated answer :)

Comment: But then I loose typescript type hinting. its not "strong" inside setstate

Comment: It's interesting how that page you linked also says that `this.state` should be directly set from the constructor and to not use `setState` there. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: @WiredPrairie, i think you get confused, what it means is outside of constructor always use setState to **update** the state value, but to update something first we need to initialise. So inside constructor first we have to define the state object, there setState will not work (because setState is for update). once we define the state object then we need to use setState, hope you will get the idea :)

Comment: I’m not confused. The docs use absolutes, as does your answer, in misleading ways.

Answer (score 0):

Other Places then `constructor`, you need to call `setState` method to change `state`.

```
closeLeftCol() {
            this.setState({
                //change state here
                leftWidth: "0",
                rightWidth: "100%",
                leftClassName: this.state.leftClassName + " hideme",
                rightClassName: this.state.rightClassName + " full"
            })
            //or use this way
            this.setState((prevState)=>{
                return {
                    //change state here
                    leftWidth: "0",
                    rightWidth: "100%",
                    leftClassName: prevState.leftClassName + " hideme",
                    rightClassName: prevState.rightClassName + " full"
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: But then I loose typescript type hinting. its not "strong" inside setstate

Comment: @Shazam You can update state only using `setState` . There is no other method. However, you can use `setState` in two ways - by passing new state object, or by passing a function that returns a new state. I have updated the answer. Check if it works for you. Sorry, I don't much about typescript type hinting.